# How can I get the ModelPath or ModelGUID of a Revit Cloud file only knowing the filename, folder ID and procejt ID? Without Forge

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

I have a method where I take a newly created Revit file and I save it as a Cloud Workshared model and return its ModelPath.
When there is already a revit file with the same name on the folder I get a Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.RevitServerModelAlreadyExistsException. I want to catch that exception and return the model path of the existing file instead but can't find a way to get it without using Forge.

```
public static ModelPath SaveAsCloud(Document currentDocument, string modelName, string folderId)
{
    Guid account = new Guid(accountId);
    Guid project = new Guid(projectId);
    try
    {
        currentDocument.SaveAsCloudModel(account, project, folderId, modelName); //Doesnt work if the model already exists
        currentDocument.EnableCloudWorksharing();
        ModelPath modelPath = currentDocument.GetCloudModelPath();
        return modelPath;
    }
    catch (RevitServerModelAlreadyExistsException)
    {
        ModelPath modelPathExisting = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(ModelPathUtils.CloudRegionUS, project, modelGuid); //Missing the modelGuid!!
        return modelPathExisting;
    }

}
```

I was looking into using ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath() t get the cloudPath but I'm missing the last argument which is the modelGUID. Any way to retrieve it with the information that I already have without Forge?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if using APS(Forge) is fine, then you can use the search API https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/, just filter[attributes.displayName]-contains="fileName".

But if Revit API only, I don't think there is a way to get the Revit Cloud Model information from the name by Revit API.